# Select portion of the uiimage with given color

Tags: ios, uiimage, core-graphics, core-image

I would like to implement a feature that allows user to select a given color from the image and replace it with transparent color. Ideally it would work similar to Pixelmator, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=taXGaQC0JBg where user can select colors and see which portions of the image are currently selected and a slider that can be used to select the tolerance of the colors.

My primary suspect for the replacing colors is CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors() function. Perhaps CIColorCube might do the job. 
I am not sure how to proceed with visualizing the selection of the colors. Any tips will be welcome!
thank you,
Janusz

EDIT:
I am moving very slowly but I made some progress. I am using imageCreateWithMaskingColors function to extract unwanted colors:

```
    func imageWithMaskingColors(){
        //get uiimage
        let image:CGImageRef = self.inputImage.image!.CGImage
        let maskingColors :[CGFloat] = [0,200,0,255,0,255]


        let newciimage = CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors(image,maskingColors)

        let newImage = UIImage(CGImage: newciimage)
        self.outputImage.image = newImage
        let w = CGFloat(CGImageGetWidth(newciimage))
        let h = CGFloat(CGImageGetHeight(newciimage))
        let size = CGSizeMake(w,h)

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0.0)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

        newImage?.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h))

        let result  = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        self.inputImage1 = result.CGImage
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


    }
```

[image: Extracting Colors]

In the next step I am applying a CISourceOutCompositing CIFilter to get a selected area, that was removed in last step:
 @IBAction func blendMode(){

```
    let context = CIContext(options: nil)
    let inputImage:CIImage = CIImage(CGImage:self.inputImage1)
    var filter = CIFilter(name: "CISourceOutCompositing")
    println(inputImage.debugDescription)

    //mix it with black
    let fileURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("black", withExtension: "jpg")
    var backgroundImage = CIImage(contentsOfURL: fileURL)
    filter.setValue(inputImage, forKey: kCIInputBackgroundImageKey)
     filter.setValue(backgroundImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    println(backgroundImage.debugDescription)
    let outputImage = filter.outputImage
    println(outputImage.debugDescription)
    let cgimg = context.createCGImage(outputImage, fromRect: outputImage.extent())

    blendImage1 = cgimg

    let newImage = UIImage(CGImage: cgimg)

    self.outputImage.image = newImage

}
```

[image: Selected Area]
In the next step I would like to add a dashed-stroke line to borders and remove the filling color of the selected image (black tiger).

I used a GPUImage CannyEdgeDetectionFilter to the image but it didn't give me satysfiying results (black image)

```
let gpaPicture = GPUImagePicture(CGImage: blendImage1)
        let canny = GPUImageCannyEdgeDetectionFilter()
        //canny.upperThreshold = CGFloat(1125)
        canny.lowerThreshold = CGFloat(1)
        gpaPicture.addTarget(canny)
        canny.useNextFrameForImageCapture()
        gpaPicture.processImage()
        let gpuResult = canny.imageByFilteringImage(UIImage(CGImage:blendImage1))
```